# I want to sort JSONArray by one value and return sorted array

Tags: java, json

Here is my first program using JSON. It is almost finished, only needs to be sorted by the "updated_at" value, and then return the sorted result in the form "name" + "updated_at". Anyone can help me with this / write code?
How can i do this?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ArrayWithAllRepos arrayWithAllRepos = new ArrayWithAllRepos();

    String dataFromPage1 = URLReader.readUrl(AllegroURL.URL_1);
    String dataFromPage2 = URLReader.readUrl(AllegroURL.URL_2);
    String dataFromPage3 = URLReader.readUrl(AllegroURL.URL_3);

    JSONArray jsonArrayWithDataFromPage1 = new JSONArray(dataFromPage1);
    JSONArray jsonArrayWithDataFromPage2 = new JSONArray(dataFromPage2);
    JSONArray jsonArrayWithDataFromPage3 = new JSONArray(dataFromPage3);

    arrayWithAllRepos.addToJsonToArray(jsonArrayWithDataFromPage1);
    arrayWithAllRepos.addToJsonToArray(jsonArrayWithDataFromPage2);
    arrayWithAllRepos.addToJsonToArray(jsonArrayWithDataFromPage3);

    arrayWithAllRepos.printArray(arrayWithAllRepos.getJsonArray());
}
```

}

```
public class AllegroURL {

public static final String URL_1 = "https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?pagelen=1000&page=1";
public static final String URL_2 = "https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?pagelen=1000&page=2";
public static final String URL_3 = "https://api.github.com/users/allegro/repos?pagelen=1000&page=3";
```

}

Comment: Please remove the code not related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the class `ArrayWithAllRepos`, but you can create `Comparator` which gets two json objects, and compare them with this value (you can see a lot of examples in google, here is one https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/)

and use `.stream().map()` methods on the collection, in order to change the output (again, you can see a lot of examples in google, here is one https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/05/java-8-filter-map-collect-stream-example.html)

If your collection does not support `stream()`, you can do a simple for, and create new json with you values.